# Unable to install git in redhat linux server

Tags: linux, git, redhat

While installing git in redhat linux it asked for few dependencies for installation of git.

i downloaded them nut while installing it throughs below error.

[root@sudhakar ~]# rpm -ivh git-1.7.1-2.el6_0.1.x86_64.rpm
warning: git-1.7.1-2.el6_0.1.x86_64.rpm: Header V4 DSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID 192a7d7d: NOKEY
error: Failed dependencies:
        perl(Git) is needed by git-1.7.1-2.el6_0.1.x86_64
        perl-Git = 1.7.1-2.el6_0.1 is needed by git-1.7.1-2.el6_0.1.x86_64

[root@sudhakar ~]# rpm -ivh perl-Git-1.7.1-2.el6_0.1.noarch.rpm
warning: perl-Git-1.7.1-2.el6_0.1.noarch.rpm: Header V4 DSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID 192a7d7d: NOKEY
error: Failed dependencies:
        git = 1.7.1-2.el6_0.1 is needed by perl-Git-1.7.1-2.el6_0.1.noarch

Whereas i have downloaded both the packages required here, but unable to install any of them.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you trying to install such an old version of Git?

Answer (score 1):

Use yum localinstall  git-1.7.1-2.el6_0.1.x86_64.rpm. It will automatically download the required dependencies if you have yum repositories configured.